# Creating a replacement 'shell'/desktop on WinCE

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-ce

I'm developing for a WinCE 7 kiosk-like device. It will spend almost all its time running one application, which the user should not be able to alt-tab out of, but during development only I want to be able to close the application and run various utilities.

I've removed 'explorer.exe' from startup. This correctly removes start menu, alt-tab, etc. But it means the desktop is a never-redrawn blank zone, and some parts of the application which expect WindowFromPoint() to always return a non-NULL handle are upset.

I would like to create a small application which has the same property as the desktop, of being 'glued' to the back of the screen below all other windows. How do I do this?

Edit: I've got something working with an undecorated window WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE the size of the screen which also catches WM_CLOSE. Any other magic required?

Answer (score 0):

Just configure your application launch inside HKLM\Init.
You can just replace explorer.exe with your own executable name to have it started at boot (provided that it's inside the image or on the device used to store hive-based registry).